# There's a bijective correspondence between complements of a submodule $N \leqslant M$ and extensions of $\sigma : N \approx M_1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

Let $N$ be a submodule of $R$-module $M$.  let $\sigma : N \approx M_1$ be an $R$-isomorphism.  Then the correspondence $H \to \bar{\sigma}$, where $\ker(\bar{\sigma}) = H$ is a bijection from the complements of $N$ (i.e. $H \oplus N = M$) onto extensions of $\sigma$.

*Proof*.  It's clearly one-to-one since $\ker(\sigma) = \ker(\tau) \implies H_{\sigma} = H_{\tau}$.  Now we need to show that every extension $\tau$ of $\sigma$ has a kernel that's a complement.  I don't know how to show that.  I believe we have to show it using internal direct sum.

Answer (score 0):

From the book, $N \oplus \ker(\tau) = M$.

*Proof*.  Let $H = \ker(\tau). \ $  $N \cap H = \ker{\sigma} = 0$ since $\sigma$ is an $R$-isomorphism.

Next we have to show that $N + H = M. \ $  Let $a \in M$.  Then by surjectivity of $\sigma$, $\sigma(b) = \tau(a)$ for some $b \in N$.    Then $\tau(a-b)$ = $\tau(a) - \tau(b) = 0$.  So $a = b + (a - b) \in N + H$.